# ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList) throws SOMETIMES UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist

I have a code that read list from some paged string data. What I do not understand - **why the UnsupportedOperationException is thrown on addAll() and why it's kind of random behaviour ?**

I know creating target ArrayList and not adding to the returned one solves the issue, I'm looking for better understanding not a fix.

```
List<Event> eventList = eventTable.getEvents(); // returns ArrayList
while (hasNextPage()) {
  goToNextPage();
  eventList.addAll(eventTable.getEvents());
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`List<Event>` is not necessarily an `ArrayList<Event>`. (The opposite is true though.)

The reason you get `UnsupportedOperationException` sometimes, is because `eventTable.getEvents()` *sometimes* returns a list that supports `addAll` and sometimes it doesn't.

The implementation of `getEvents` could for instance look like this:

```
if (noEventsAvailable) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
} else {
    List<Event> toReturn = new ArrayList<Event>();
    // populate list...
    return toReturn;
}
```

(In your comment you write `// returns ArrayList`. I don't know where you've got this from, but I know one thing for sure: An `ArrayList` will *always* support the `addAll` operation.)

The correct way to solve it is, as you mention, to do

```
List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>(eventTable.getEvents());
```

Comment: Often it is an array that was wrapped with Arrays.asList()

Comment: You're right, I missed the default Collections.emptyList(). It must be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the actual implementation of `List`.

e.g if the underlying list was obtained using [Collections.unmodifiableList()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) then calling `addAll()` or any other modification method will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 0):

When it throws an exception, it should show you the exact line number and source code file - you should be able to find out exactly *why* it's throwing an exception.

My guess is that under certain circumstances, `eventTable.getEvents()` returns an immutable list, or something like that - but without knowing what `eventTable` is, it's hard to say for sure. If you can produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would make it a lot easier to diagnose.